# Suggest text input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I try to create a suggest text input field read the suggest information from mysql database when a user enter a letter **for example** **A** all word contain letter **A** appear under the input field i use PHP and mysql.

**The HTML**

```
<label for="email">Location *</label>
  <input type="text" list="mylocation" id="suggest" name="txt_location">
        <datalist id="mylocation">

        </datalist>
    </div>
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
include("../includes/connect.php");
$location=$_GET['txt_location'];
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select DISTINCT(db_location) from tbl_marketing where db_location like '$location%' order by db_location")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($conn)){
        $loc=$row['db_location'];
        echo"<option value='$loc'>";
    }}
?>
```

**My Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#suggest").keyup(function(){
      $.get("suggest.php",{location: $("#suggest").val()},function(data){
          $("datalist").empty();
          $("datalist").html(data);

      }); 
   }); 
});
```

I use also in my website **bootstrap** 
The problem is that my code didn't work. Is there any other method can i do that or can i use bootstrap to do it and What is and How to do it ??!!

Comment: The question seem broad.. Perhaps break it down into smaller pieces and explain what you have tried.

Comment: @Reality-Torrent this the code i have tried but i didn't have any result.

Comment: try change this `$location=$_GET['txt_location'];` to this `$location=$_GET['location'];`

Comment: try to inspect using developer tools (in chrome) to see what's wrong. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwoT18tp6Hs

Comment: @dann it didn't work no result

Comment: @dann after to try to inspect using developer tools i see this error undefined index: txt_location

Comment: @dann How can i solve this problem ??

Comment: @m7md check your $_GET with print_r($_GET)

Comment: Thanks i solve it the error is in the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Hope it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('keyup',"#suggest",function(){
      $.get("suggest.php",{txt_location: $("#suggest").val()},function(data){
          console.log(data);
          $("#mylocation").empty();
          $("#mylocation").append(data);
      }); 
   }); 
});
```

Troubleshooting steps:

1. Check if datalist is working. (Add some dummy `<option>` set)
2. Check if **suggest.php** is connected and providing you result. Use `console.log`.

Basically your script is correct except the `txt_location` and `location` i.e., key value pair mismatch.

Comment: after to try to inspect using developer tools i see this error undefined index: txt_location

Comment: Option 1 = `$.get("suggest.php",{txt_location: $("#suggest").val()},function(data){`

Comment: Option 2 = `$location=$_GET['location'];`

Answer (score 0):

try this PHP code

```
<?php
include("../includes/connect.php");
$location=$_GET['location'];
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select DISTINCT(db_location) from tbl_marketing where db_location like '".$location."%' order by db_location")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($conn)){
        $loc=$row['db_location'];
        echo"<option value='$loc'>";
    }
}
?>
```